# You cannot .filter() on a DjangoCassandraQuerySet which has been ordered using python

Tags: python, django, cassandra

When I want to delete a bulk of data by checked all from Django admin, then go, then this error has happened.

My cassandra model:

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django.utils import timezone
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel


class MyModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    requested_data = columns.Text(default="")
    response = columns.Text(default="")
    created_at = columns.DateTime(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = columns.DateTime(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use filter in Django ORM:

```
ETrafficPayment.objects.filter(id=id).order_by('created_at')
```

You can reverse as well

```
ETrafficPayment.objects.filter(id=id).order_by('created_at').reverse()
```

Comment: I am not asking about django orm. Trying to delete data from django admin panel.